# Is there a simpler way that to skip from node explored in tree? [C#]

Tags: c#, recursion, tree

I have a tree that can have the same node.

If it found the node explored, then I want to skip the node.

Of course, this is a simple topic but I am curious if there is a simpler way.

The code that comes to mind is something like this:

```
void Explore(Tree tree, HashSet<Tree> exploredTrees)
{
    if (exploredTrees.Contains(tree)) 
        continue;

    foreach(var childTree in tree.ChildTree)
    {
        Explore(childTree);
        exploredTrees.Add(childTree);
    }
}

void static Program()
{
    // it assumes there is data in the tree.
    Tree tree = new Tree();

    Explore(tree, new HashSet());
}
```

I've been using the code above so far but the second parameter getting on my nerves (`new HashSet()` for the above example).

As you know to achieve this purpose it must need a data structure to store the data explored.

However, I'm not satisfied because the data structure has to pass from the external. (ex: `Explore(tree, new HashSet())`)

Is there a way to achieve this purpose without the second parameter in C#?

I don't want to use static keyword because it has to remember to clear the data structure at external.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Can't you just overload the `Explore` method or initialize the `exploredTrees` parameter to null and instantiate it if it's null?

Comment: Thank you. Each time it is called, the overhead of the if statement will occur, but it seems to be the best method for now.

Answer (score 1):

The general approach is correct, but you could simply add a helper method that creates the hashSet for you: `void Explore(Tree tree) => Explore(tree, new HashSet<Tree>())`

Or you could use an iterative solution that lets you keep the HashSet as a local variable:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> DepthFirstLoopSafe<T>(T self, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> selector, IEqualityComparer<T> equalityComparer = default)
{
    var stack = new Stack<T>();
    var visited = new HashSet<T>(equalityComparer ?? EqualityComparer<T>.Default);
    stack.Push(self);
    while (stack.Count > 0)
    {
        var current = stack.Pop();
        visited.Add(current);
        yield return current;
        foreach (var child in selector(current))
        {
            if (!visited.Contains(child))
            {
                stack.Push(child);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Called like `DepthFirstLoopSafe(tree, t => t.ChildTree)`. I like to use generics to describe the iteration of trees, since it allows reuse of code for all kinds of trees, regardless of type or how the tree is described.

Comment: Oh, Thank you. It's a method I've never seen before. I will study your code.

Comment: @jjw you might also want to read Raymond Chens article on [Considering the performance implications of converting recursion to an explicit stack](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180927-00/?p=99835)